# Manage what appears in "News from Sites"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm looking to see if anybody else has found a way to manage what appears in "News from sites" when a user logs on to SharePoint.  Even changing the "Promoted State" of News Pages to 0 doesn't seem to effect what I see in my News from sites.

I'm curious if anybody has a found a solution, whether it requires an Azure Function, Flow, PnP, CSOM, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "Promoted State" of a News Page to `0` using SharePoint Designer, then waited for a while and refreshed the page. Then, this page is not in News web part on the page.

The news pages are getting display when they have been crawled in search. You need to wait for the next crawl, so that the changes will get effect.

In SharePoint Online, crawling happens automatically based on the defined crawl schedule. And the crawling time will increase if it is a heavy environment.

We cannot manually start a full crawl for contents or control crawl in SharePoint online.
You can request a re-indexing of the library to resubmit content to the crawl.

Introduction to SharePoint Online Search and some troubleshooting steps:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Support-Blog/Introduction-to-SharePoint-Online-Search/ba-p/170708

Comment: Hi JoannaW, thank you very much for your response.  I do not think I am referring to the News Web Part per se, but the "News from site section one sees when they first login to their SharePoint site, like contoso.sharepoint.com.  Is your answer specifically referring to a SharePoint News web part?  Or will this also apply to the News from sites one sees upon first logging in (Assuming their Office 365 settings are set to start on SharePoint upon logging in).  Thank you!